# Angular custom library ngFor and ngIF error

Tags: angular

Angular custom library throw error for **`ngIF`** and **`ngFor`**

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgForOf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgForOf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!
```

Comment: Hi AnilK. Could you give us more info and show us your app.module.ts code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable preserveSymlinks inside your build configuration in angular.json

In your angular.json locate build property under the architect, and in options add `"preserveSymlinks": true`
I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: in library build configuration :

 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "preserveSymlinks": true,

and in Application webpack configuration :

resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.css', '.sass'],
        symlinks: true
           
 }

but still getting same error

Comment: If you are still getting an error then delete node modules of your project and do npm install and then try to run.

Comment: In addition to that you can follow this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11454 may be you can find some needful that will solve your problem so that you can conclued thanks.